# codeigniter can't Insert record to database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, activerecord

i got an error like this

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘Satuan, `Satuan`) VALUES (‘KMJ001’, ‘KKMJ005’, ‘asdf asdf’, ‘123123’, ‘kg’)’ at line 1

INSERT INTO `ms_material_jasa` (`Kode_Material_Jasa`, `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`, `Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa`, `Harga` Satuan, `Satuan`) VALUES (‘KMJ001’, ‘KKMJ005’, ‘asdf asdf’, ‘123123’, ‘kg’)
```

it refers to my active record model

```
function create($kmj,$kkmj,$njmj,$hs,$s)
{
    $data=array('Kode_Material_Jasa' => $kmj, 'Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa' => $kkmj, 'Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa' => $njmj, 'Harga Satuan' => $hs, 'Satuan' => $s);
    $this->db->insert('ms_material_jasa',$data);

}
```

here is my controller

```
 function tambah()
{
   $data['kmj'] = $this->input->post('kmj');
   $data['kkmj'] = $this->input->post('kkmj');
   $data['njmj'] = $this->input->post('njmj');
   $data['hs'] = $this->input->post('hs');
   $data['s'] = $this->input->post('s');


   $data['title'] = 'QB Tambah Material / Jasa';
   $data['pesan'] = $data['kmj'].' berhasil ditambahkan ! ';


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('kmj','Kode Material / Jasa','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('kkmj','Kode Kategori Material / Jasa','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('njmj','Nama Jenis Material / Jasa','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hs','Harga Satuan','trim|required|min_length[2]|numeric|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('s','Satuan','xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $lastval = $this->m_admin->getlastval('KMJ','ms_material_jasa','kode_material_jasa');
        $data['nextval'] = $this->m_admin->gencode('KMJ',3,$lastval); 


        $this->load->view('head',$data);
        $this->load->view('content/add_material_jasa',$data);
    }
    else
    {

        $this->m_materialjasa->create($data['kmj'],$data['kkmj'],$data['njmj'],$data['hs'],$data['s']);
        $data['kirim'] = $this->m_materialjasa->read();
        $this->load->view('head',$data);
        $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial',$data);


    }

}
```

looks like the following query

```
INSERT INTO `ms_material_jasa` (`Kode_Material_Jasa`, `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`, `Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa`, `Harga` Satuan, `Satuan`) VALUES (‘KMJ001’, ‘KKMJ005’, ‘asdf asdf’, ‘123123’, ‘kg’)
```

is correct, here is the `ms_material_jasa` table. it looks like the entry don't break the data type.length on database. i don't know what went wrong, how do i resolve this ? 
[image]

Comment: PS. You might want to actually go back and accept the answers people have given you over the last few days. 62% accept is pretty low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quote is in the wrong place on 'Harga Satuan' in the fields list. The error actually says that.
Yours:

```
INSERT INTO `ms_material_jasa` (`Kode_Material_Jasa`, `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`, `Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa`, `Harga` Satuan, `Satuan`) VALUES (‘KMJ001’, ‘KKMJ005’, ‘asdf asdf’, ‘123123’, ‘kg’)
```

Correct:

```
INSERT INTO `ms_material_jasa` (`Kode_Material_Jasa`, `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`, `Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa`, `Harga_Satuan`, `Satuan`) VALUES (‘KMJ001’, ‘KKMJ005’, ‘asdf asdf’, ‘123123’, ‘kg’)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have placed incorrect field name. Please correct this, put `Harga_Satuan` instead of `Harga Satuan`

```
function create($kmj,$kkmj,$njmj,$hs,$s)
{
    $data=array('Kode_Material_Jasa' => $kmj, 'Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa' => $kkmj, 'Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa' => $njmj, 'Harga_Satuan' => $hs, 'Satuan' => $s);
    $this->db->insert('ms_material_jasa',$data);

}
```

and your query should be

```
INSERT INTO `ms_material_jasa` (`Kode_Material_Jasa`, `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`, `Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa`, `Harga_Satuan`, `Satuan`) VALUES (‘KMJ001’, ‘KKMJ005’, ‘asdf asdf’, ‘123123’, ‘kg’)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem probably is hear
'Harga Satuan' => $hs
There is no such field.

Answer (score 0):

correct one is

```
INSERT INTO `ms_material_jasa` (`Kode_Material_Jasa`, `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`, `Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa`, `Harga Satuan`, `Satuan`) VALUES ('KMJ001', 'KKMJ005', 'asdf asdf', '123123', 'kg')
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the active record is failing to put the apostrophe in `Harga` Satuan,

```
 $data=array('Kode_Material_Jasa' => $kmj, 'Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa' => $kkmj, 'Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa' => $njmj, 'Harga Satuan' => $hs, 'Satuan' => $s);
    $this->db->insert('ms_material_jasa',$data);
```

that maybe because of the space between words and in the database is with and underscore.
to correct this change the code like this.

```
function create($kmj,$kkmj,$njmj,$hs,$s)
{
  $data=array('Kode_Material_Jasa' => $kmj, 'Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa' => $kkmj, 'Nama_Jenis_Material_Jasa' => $njmj, 'Harga_Satuan' => $hs, 'Satuan' => $s);
$this->db->insert('ms_material_jasa',$data);


}
```

.

hope it solve the problem.